# Cannot append string to dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, append, key-value

I've been programming for less than four weeks and have run into a problem that I cannot figure out. I'm trying to append a string value to an existing key with an existing string stored in it but if any value already exists in the key I get "str object has no attribute 'append'.

I've tried turning the value to list but this also does not work. I need to use the .append() attribute because update simply replaces the value in clientKey instead of appending to whatever value is already stored. After doing some more research, I understand now that I need to somehow split the value stored in clientKey.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data = {}

while True:

    clientKey = input().upper()
    refDate = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", gmtime())
    refDate = refDate[2 : ]
    ref = clientKey + refDate

    if clientKey not in data:
        data[clientKey] = ref

    elif ref in data[clientKey]:
        print("That invoice already exists")

    else:
        data[clientKey].append(ref)

        break
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for the assistance. It's running as it should. I also appreciate the advice on defaultdict. It sounds like a sensible way to simplify and compact the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't `.append()` to a string because a string is not mutable.  If you want your dictionary value to be able to contain multiple items, it should be a container type such as a list. The easiest way to do this is just to add the single item as a list in the first place.

```
if clientKey not in data:
    data[clientKey] = [ref]   # single-item list
```

Now you can `data[clientkey].append()` all day long.

A simpler approach for this problem is to use `collections.defaultdict`. This automatically creates the item when it's not there, making your code much simpler.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

# ... same as before up to your if

if clientkey in data and ref in data[clientkey]:
    print("That invoice already exists")
else:
    data[clientKey].append(ref)
```

Answer (score 2):

You started with a string value, and you cannot call `.append()` on a string. Start with a list value instead:

```
if clientKey not in data:
    data[clientKey] = [ref]
```

Now `data[clientKey]` references a list object with one string in it. List objects *do* have an `append()` method.

Comment: Thanks this help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep appending to the string you can use `data[clientKey]+= ref`